# Sublime Text 3 + Sass Auto-highlight

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

After Install the Package for sass extensions in Sublime 3 when I open a scss file all goes good but when I open a sass file there isn't auto highlited the text.

I have read that is a conflict with this  file *Data/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage.*

What can I do to auto-highlight sass files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is about the ST2, but can be useful for you:

> Sublime allows you to specify what syntax to use for a given file
>   extension.
>
> To force Sublime to correctly highlight sass files: 1. Open a sass
>   file. 2. Click View | Syntax | Open all with current extension as … |
>   Sass.

http://sublimetexttips.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/